# IntelliJ: almost unreadable fonts on linux

Tags: linux, fonts, intellij-idea

As you can see on the screenshot, most of the text on IntelliJ renders as it should, however, on certain elements, such as the code lens, the fonts are almost unreadable. 
On the `Help -> About` I get:

> IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1
>
> Build #IU-145.597, built on March 29, 2016
>
> JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b18 amd64
>
> JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

And I'm using opensuse Leap 42.1 Gnome, if that makes any difference.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known bug :
[Clion 2016.1.1 code lens on Linux shows unreadable aliased bold font text](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-153987).

> In Clion 2016.1.1, the lens mode on Linux (opensuse leap 42.1) looks
>   bad. It shows bold text which is aliased and unreadable. This problem
>   is the same across themes and font settings. See attached file. 
> The
>   lens mode used to work just fine in Clion 1.2.4 with proper
>   anti-aliasing in place.

The only [workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-153987#comment=27-1381285) is to set the antialiasing settings for the editor to greyscale from subpixel.
Although it is [remarked](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-153987#comment=27-1383185) that when the new mouse-over text box pops-up, it will be aliased for a split second and then rendered correctly.
Or you could always go back to the previous version.

The problem seems to be under consideration, although the proposed bug-fix
was ineffective.

Comment: Thank you so much. The workaround is good enough for me. Also, setting the IDE antialias to grayscale also helps with mouse-over text box on the partially obstructed elements on the project tree.

Comment: You could perhaps add your feedback to this bug report.